# Split adjacent overlines

Tags: math-mode, overline

The sequence `4813065297` has 5 adjacent pairs in descending order; namely `81`, `30`, `65`, `52`, `97`. I want to highlight these pairs by means of overlines, but the pair `65` overlaps with `52`, so I can only get a continuous overline:

`\[4\overline{81}\overline{30}\overline{652}\overline{97}\]`

**Q:** How can I get an overline from `6` to the middle of `5`, followed by another from there to `2`, with a small visible gap?

Comment: Maybe you're interested in a command that also computes by itself the overlines. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `\overline`s will run into each other, so first is needed a narrowed overline, to leave a gap.

Here, I create `\noverline` (narrow-overline) that uses kerning tricks to narrow the width of the overline, based on the length that is `\def`ed into `\nindent`.

Then, you need something to do what the question asks, create an overline that leave a gap midway.  For that, I create `\midoverline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\nindent{.5pt}
\newcommand\noverline[1]{%
  \kern\nindent\overline{\kern-\nindent#1\kern-\nindent}\kern\nindent}
\newcommand\midoverline[1]{%
  \sbox0{$#1$}%
  \bgroup\ooalign{$#1$\cr$\noverline{\rule{.5\wd0}{0pt}\vphantom{#1}}%
  \noverline{\rule{.5\wd0}{0pt}\vphantom{#1}}$}\egroup
}
\begin{document}
\[4\noverline{81}\noverline{30}\midoverline{652}\noverline{97}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was not straightforward. This type of answer helps me learn.

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce the length of the overline and exploit that the digits all have the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newmuskip\ovskip
\ovskip=1mu

\newcommand{\decr}[1]{%
  \mspace{\ovskip}%
  \overline{\mspace{-\ovskip}#1\mspace{-\ovskip}}%
  \mspace{\ovskip}%
}
\newcommand{\decrdbl}[3]{%
  \decr{#1\hspace{0.5\fontcharwd\textfont0`0}}%
  \hspace{-0.5\fontcharwd\textfont0`0}%
  #2%
  \hspace{-0.5\fontcharwd\textfont0`0}%
  \decr{\hspace{0.5\fontcharwd\textfont0`0}#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
4\decr{81}\decr{30}\decrdbl{6}{5}{2}\decr{97}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\ovskip=1.5mu` you'd get

[image]

Experiment what seems the best for your taste.

### Automatic version

Just for fun, here's a version that does all the work for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newmuskip\ovskip
\ovskip=1mu

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\markdecrease}{m}
 {
  \yrodro_markdecrease:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl
\seq_new:N \l__yrodro_markdecrease_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yrodro_markdecrease:n
 {
  % typeset the number
  #1
  % back up
  \hspace{-\tl_count:n { #1 } \fontcharwd\textfont0`0}
  % compute the overlines
  \tl_clear:N \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl
  \__yrodro_markdecrease:NN #1 \q_nil
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yrodro_markdecrease:NN
 {
  \quark_if_nil:NTF { #2 }
   {% end of the recursion, add the last digit
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl { #1 }
    % split at periods
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__yrodro_markdecrease_seq { . } \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl
    % produce the overlines
    \seq_map_function:NN \l__yrodro_markdecrease_seq \__yrodro_markdecrease_item:n
   }
   {% there are more digits, add the first one
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl { #1 }
    % if the next digit is not less than the current one, add a period
    \int_compare:nF { #1 > #2 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl { . }
     }
    % restart the recursion with the next digit as the first one
    \__yrodro_markdecrease:NN #2
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yrodro_markdecrease_item:n
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \tl_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    {1}{ \__yrodro_markdecrease_blank: }
    {2}{ \__yrodro_markdecrease_over:n {00} }
   }
   { \__yrodro_markdecrease_more:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yrodro_markdecrease_blank:
 {
  \phantom{0}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yrodro_markdecrease_over:n
 {
  \mspace{\ovskip}
  \overline{\mspace{-\ovskip}\phantom{#1}\mspace{-\ovskip}}
  \mspace{\ovskip}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yrodro_markdecrease_more:n
 {
  \__yrodro_markdecrease_oneandhalf:
  \prg_replicate:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } - 3 } { \__yrodro_markdecrease_over:n {0} }
  \__yrodro_markdecrease_oneandhalf:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yrodro_markdecrease_oneandhalf:
 {
  \mspace{\ovskip}
  \overline{\mspace{-\ovskip}\phantom{0}\hspace{0.5\fontcharwd\textfont0`0}\mspace{-\ovskip}}
  \mspace{\ovskip}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\markdecrease{4813065297}\quad\markdecrease{9876543210}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different version that draws overlines starting from and ending at the middle of digits (with a small gap).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newmuskip\ovskip
\ovskip=1mu

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\markdecrease}{m}
 {
  \yrodro_markdecrease:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl
\seq_new:N \l__yrodro_markdecrease_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yrodro_markdecrease:n
 {
  % typeset the number
  #1
  % back up
  \hspace{-\tl_count:n { #1 } \fontcharwd\textfont0`0}
  % compute the overlines
  \tl_clear:N \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl
  \__yrodro_markdecrease:NN #1 \q_nil
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yrodro_markdecrease:NN
 {
  \quark_if_nil:NTF { #2 }
   {% end of the recursion, add the last digit
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl { #1 }
    % split at periods
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__yrodro_markdecrease_seq { . } \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl
    % produce the overlines
    \seq_map_function:NN \l__yrodro_markdecrease_seq \__yrodro_markdecrease_item:n
   }
   {% there are more digits, add the first one
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl { #1 }
    % if the next digit is not less than the current one, add a period
    \int_compare:nF { #1 > #2 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__yrodro_markdecrease_tl { . }
     }
    % restart the recursion with the next digit as the first one
    \__yrodro_markdecrease:NN #2
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yrodro_markdecrease_item:n
 {
  \hspace{0.5\fontcharwd\textfont0`0}
  \prg_replicate:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } - 1 }
   {
    \mspace{\ovskip}
    \overline{\mspace{-\ovskip}\phantom{0}\mspace{-\ovskip}}
    \mspace{\ovskip}
   }
  \hspace{0.5\fontcharwd\textfont0`0}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\markdecrease{4813065297}\quad\markdecrease{9876543210}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]